# how to efficiently do a reverse look up in defaultdict?

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, defaultdict

I did some search before posting this question, it seems there are few different ways to accomplish this.

But what is the most efficient way currently (using Python 3) to search for a key based on a specific value in a `defaultdict` which looks (something) like this:

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'a': [[2, 3], [1, 2]],
             'b': [[5, 6]],
             'w': [[]],
             'x': [[9]],
             'z': [[5, 6]]})
```

I want to find all keys that have a value of say 6. One solution is to write a nested for loop that iterates over the key, value of the `defaultdict`, but I am sure there is a better way to accomplish this.

Comment: what do you mean by most-efficient. You have to be content with an `O(n)` algorithm (`n` being all the items in all values.). Additional question: Do you plan to make one lookup or several?

Comment: Several lookups. Thanks.

Comment: Roughly: create a custom class, derived from dictionary.  Over-ride insert and modify methods to update/maintain your reverse key/value dictionary.  Provide a *reverse_lookup()* method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `chain.from_iterable` from `itertools` module like this example:

```
from itertools import chain 

a = defaultdict(list,
            {'a': [[2, 3], [1, 2]],
             'b': [[5, 6]],
             'w': [[]],
             'x': [[9]],
             'z': [[5, 6]]})

keys =  [k for k, v in a.items() if 6 in chain.from_iterable(v)]
print(keys)
```

Or, in a more compact way, you can define a function that do a lookup in your defaultdict's values:

```
def get_keys(a, key=6):
    return [k for k, v in a.items() if key in chain.from_iterable(v)]

keys = get_keys(a)
print(keys)
```

Output:

```
['b', 'z']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing several lookups (and [in the comments you said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44532374/how-to-efficiently-do-a-reverse-look-up-in-defaultdict#comment76056647_44532374) you planned to do several) it might be useful to actually create a reversed defauldict:

```
from collections import defaultdict

inp = defaultdict(list, {'a': [[2, 3], [1, 2]], 'b': [[5, 6]], 'w': [[]], 'x': [[9]], 'z': [[5, 6]]})

res = defaultdict(set)

for key, vallist in inp.items():
    for valsublist in vallist:
        for val in valsublist:
            res[val].add(key)
```

And then just access the `res` to do the lookups.

For example:

```
>>> res[6]
{'z', 'b'}

>>> res[2]
{'a'}
```

You'll always need to iterate over all the items in all your defaultdicts values (which takes `O(n)` where `n` is the number of all items in all value lists). But looking up a key in a dictionary is (mostly) `O(1)`. So if you plan to do several inquiries, say `k`, then doing the iteration multiple times takes `O(n*k)` but converting it to another dict would be only `O(n + k)`. At least if one assumes that the `set.add` operations are `O(1)`, which should be the case (except for some - really uncommon - pathological cases).

Comment: @D.prd No problem :) Please don't forget to [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) all helpful answers and [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the one that **you** found most helpful (if any).